# How to find Scripting access groups for Terminal.app

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I'm trying to run this script

```
@"tell application \"Terminal\"\nactivate\nreopen\ndo script \"cd \\\"%@\\\"\" in front window\nend tell", folderPath];
```

from sandboxed app. It requires to set `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` entitlement which in turn requires to specify set of Scripting access groups for Terminal.app

This is the issue. There is many hints how to find it using `sdef` tool but Terminal.app produces sdef definition with `Standard Suite` and `Terminal Suite` but there is not a single `access-group` definition.

I've tested this approach on Music.app and it works there fine. But not for Terminal.app

It gets worse. Using `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` is not a solution because it get rejected by Apple :-(

Comment: The target app must support access groups. Terminal.app does not. There is no workaround.

Comment: What would you like to achieve with the script? Only cd is probably not your goal. Usually there are several ways to fulfill software requirements within sandboxed applications. But there are some requirements that are contradictory to sandboxing.

Comment: "cd" only is my goal. I want to open/activate Terminal window with given path as current.

Comment: Just a thought... Terminal.app has has public services: `New Terminal at Folder` and `New Terminal Tab at Folder`, which you can invoke programmatically [as shown here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000854-97922-CEGEIEDA). That should accomplish the goal while bypassing security issues.